# How to add a single colorbar for multiple subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add a single colorbar to the set of 4 subplots that I have plotted. Here is what I have tried :

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2 , ncols=2, sharex=True)

axes = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]
y_vals = [total_first_downs, touchdowns, possession, rushing_yards]
y_labels = ['Total First Downs','Touchdowns', 'Possession Time (seconds)', 'Total Rushing Yds']
colors = wins

for i in range(4):
    axes[i].scatter(years, y_vals[i], c=colors, cmap='viridis')
    axes[i].plot(years, y_vals[i], c='g', alpha=0.5)
    axes[i].set_xticks(np.arange(2006,2020,2))
    axes[i].set_ylabel(y_labels[i])



cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Wins per Season')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I get the error `No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).`

I tried to look at similar questions but couldn't find a way to correct this.

Comment: but what do i put where he put `plt.colorbar(cs4, ax=axs)`, specifically `cs4`

Comment: `axs = ((ax1, ax2), (ax3,ax4))`?

Comment: yes but what about cs4?

Comment: I am not using contour plots so what do I have to include?

Comment: `pc = axes[i].scatter(years, y_vals[i], c=colors, cmap='viridis')` and then `plt.colorbar(pc, ax=axs)`